# Check for balanced parentheses in an expression in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write this in swift as I could not find any solution written in swift but seem to have hit a roadblock with this implementation.
On the pop and push function, I am not sure if `Character` is the right return/argument.

```
class BalancedParam {
  struct stack {
    var top = -1
    var items = [Character]()

    mutating func push(_ x: Character) {
        items.append(x)
        if top == 99 {
            print("Stack full")
        } else {
            top += 1
            items[top] = x
        }
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Character {
        if top == -1 {
            print("Underflow error")
            return "0"
        } else {
            let element = items[top]
            top -= 1
            return element
        }
    }

    mutating func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return (top == -1) ? true : false
    }
}

static func isMatchingPair(_ character1: Character, _ character2: Character) -> Bool {
    if character1 == "(" && character2 == ")"  {
        return true
    } else if character1 == "{" && character2 == "}" {
        return true
    } else if character1 == "[" && character2 == "]" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

static func areParenthesisBalanced(_ exp: [Character]) -> Bool {
    // Declare an empty character stack
    var st = stack()
    for i in 0..<exp.count {

        if exp[i] == "{" || exp[i] == "(" || exp[i] == "[" {
                st.push(exp[i])
        }

        if exp[i] == "}" || exp[i] == ")" || exp[i] == "]" {

            if st.isEmpty() {
                return false
            } else if !isMatchingPair(st.pop(), exp[i] ) {
                return false
            }

        }
    }
    if st.isEmpty() {
        return true //balanced
    } else {
        //not balanced
        return false
    }
  }
}

let exp: [Character] = ["{", "(", ")", "}", "[", "]"]
  if BalancedParam.areParenthesisBalanced(exp) {
    print("Balanced ")
  } else {
    print("Not Balanced ")
  }
```

I will appreciate any help in understanding what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: How do you know you are doing something wrong? What’s the problem?

Comment: Your code aborts with an  “Index out of range” error  because `items` is an *empty* array.

Comment: The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Thanks got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign to an empty array, i.e `items[top] = x`, you can only use this syntax if the array is of size `top+1` or larger

So this is not ok

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr[0] = 1
```

but this is

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr.append(0)
arr[0] = 1
```

Another option since you have a cap on your array size is to init an array of that size and then continue to use the original syntax

```
var arr = Array(repeating: 0, count: 99)
arr[0] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks got it fixed.